# How to perform async initalization of lazy injection

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dependency-injection, simple-injector

Let's say we want to inject an object that is expensive to create (let's say it does initialization from a database), so we would typically use some kind of factory or `Lazy<T>`.  However, if we're injecting this object into an MVC or WebApi controller that is using async action methods, we don't want to block these methods on the expensive I/O operation when the Lazy object is initialized, which defeats the purpose of using async.

Certainly, I could create an "initlize" method that is async, but that violates a number of principles.

What's the best option for accessing and initializing the injected object in a lazy and async way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the components that are part of your object graph and are auto-wired by the container should be very lightweight to create, because [injection constructors should be simple](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). Anything that is either runtime data, or one-time data that is costly to create, should not be injected directly into the constructor of a component that is part of your object graph. Async even exaggerates this, because constructors can never be asynchronous; you can't use await in the body of a constructor.

So if a component depends on some expensive to create data, this data should be loaded lazily, outside of the constructor. This way the building of the object graph becomes fast and the creation of your controllers doesn't get blocked.

So as @ScottChamberlain already said, probably the nicest way is to mix `Lazy<T>` with `Task<T>` to become `Lazy<Task<T>>`. You would probably gain the best results if you inject this `Lazy<Task<T>>` into the constructor of your 'expensive component' (making that component itself lightweight again). This has a few clear benefits:

- the previously expensive object itself becomes simple; it not responsible anymore for the loading of the data.
- the object graph becomes fast and verifiable.
- it becomes easy to change the loading strategy from lazy to background loading, without anything in the system to change.

As an example of the last point, allowing the data to be loaded in the background can be simply done as follows:

```
Task<ExpensiveData> data = Task.Run(LoadExpensiveData);

container.RegisterSingleton<ISomeClass>(
    new SomeClass(new Lazy<Task<ExpensiveData>>(() => data)));
```

Comment: Much better worded than my answer, thanks for posting! You may want to reword your last two sentences so they flow together more, I missed it the first time around that you where showing a example of *"it becomes easy to change the loading strategy from lazy to background loading, without anything in the system to change."* and was about to leave a comment saying "that is not how to do lazy loading!".

Comment: What I don't like about this approach is that it requires a 2-step initialization, rather than simply accessing the Value and initializing in the constructor.  However, I guess this is probably the best route...

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is have the thing you inject be a `Lazy<Task<T>>`, The factory would look something along the lines of

```
private Lazy<Task<Foo>> LazyFooFactory()
{
    return new Lazy<Task<Foo>>(InitFoo);
}

private async Task<Foo> InitFoo()
{
    //Other code as needed
    Foo result = await SomeSlowButAsyncronousCodeToGetFoo();
    //Other code as needed
    return result;
}
```

Used as the following

```
private readonly Lazy<Task<Foo>> _lazyFoo

public SomeClass(Lazy<Task<Foo>> lazyFoo)
{
    _lazyFoo = lazyFoo;
}

public async Task SomeFunc()
{
    //This should return quickly once the task as been started the first call
    // then will use the existing Task for subsequent calls.
    Task<Foo> fooTask = _lazyFoo.Value; 

    //This awaits for SomeSlowButAsyncronousCodeToGetFoo() to finish the first calling
    // then will used the existing result to return immediately for subsequent calls.
    var foo = await fooTask;

    DoStuffWithFoo(foo);
}
```

The function `SomeSlowButAsyncronousCodeToGetFoo()` is not called until the first calling of `_lazyFoo.Value` and subsequent calls will use the existing `Task.Result` value and not re-call the factory.

Answer (score -1):

There's a couple incorrect assumptions presented in question that should be addressed.

> ... object that is expensive to create (let's say it does initialization from a database), so we would typically use some kind of factory or `Lazy<T>`.

This is not entirely correct. `Lazy<T>` doesn't make the cost go away. Materialization of the object graph is part of the request cycle, so it happens sooner or later. `Lazy<T>` just defers the cost until `Value` is evaluated. It is **only useful in situations where you may not need to evaluate it**. Not an *optional* dependency--you may only conditionally need it, but if you do, you do.

> However, if we're ... using async action methods, we don't want to block these methods on the expensive I/O operation when the Lazy object is initialized, which defeats the purpose of using async.

But that is not the purpose of using `async`. `await` does just what it says on the tin: your method will *wait* for the awaited task to complete. What it *doesn't* block is the execution thread, which is freed to do other work in other until the CPU is "pinged" that the asynchronous work is completed ([There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)).

Summing up: `Lazy<T>` is for conditionally-required expensive dependencies. `Task` (as used with `async`) is for coordinating expensive I/O-bound (not-CPU-bound) execution so that CPU threds are not blocked. If you need to combine those, you get `Lazy<Task<T>>`, as other answerers have suggested.

[Scott's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32512523/85269) code is semantically correct, [Steven's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32518220/85269) more succinct. Combining for (I hope) both virtues:

```
Task<ExpensiveData> LoadExpensiveData() {...}

container.RegisterSingleton<ISomeClass>(
  new SomeClass(new Lazy<Task<ExpensiveData>>(() => LoadExpensiveData())));

...
public class Dependent 
{
  public Dependent(Lazy<Task<ExpensiveData>> expensivezz) {...}
  ...
}
```

Thanks to assigning the expensive function itself to `Lazy<Task<...>>` the "expense" will not be incurred until and unless `await expensivezz.Value` is evaluated. While waiting, the same thread will be freed to service other code.

#### Corollaries:

- If you only need conditional dependency, just use `Lazy<T>`.
- If you only need to keep an expensive resolution from blocking construction of your object graph (and you do! graph construction should follow the same semantic as object construction which doesn't even allow for async) then just use `Task`.
- Because most "expensive" operations are I/O-bound, and `async Task`s are now "the way" to handle these, it is probable that `Lazy<T>` implies `Lazy<Task<T>>`.

Comment: I never said `Lazy<T>` would make the cost go away.  The point was to delay the cost until it was executing under async to allow optimal thread utilization.  So even if it’s not optional it’s still useful for moving that work to an async context.  the second point was about blocking the thread when the lazy method was evaluated, I wanted to evaluate `Lazy<T>` asynchronously (because the work it was doing was io bound).. again for thread utilization reasons, not to avoid the wait.  It defeated the purpose of delaying execution to an async method if it was going to execute synchronously.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: "...it's still useful for moving that work to an async context." This is only true if your initialization requires a `SynchronizationContext`, which hopefully it does not. "...delay the cost until it was executing under `async`..." provides no benefit. `async/await` are just directives that cause the compiler to emit a lot of otherwise complex continuation code. You can *absolutely* initiate a `Task` outside an `async` block, pass it into an `async` method and then `await` it inside. You get the same non-blocking benefits, perhaps plus I/O that starts and finishes earlier.